# ProgressBar looks bizarre after reloading Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, progress-bar

So I have an app that checks for various requirements and the checking process is visualized with a `ProgressBar`. On first start, it looks just like it should. However, if I start another Activity with `startActivityForResult()` (in this case the Accessibility Settings), the app initializes the whole process again, but somehow both `ProgressBars` look very weird ([see video below](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1epWcVcdPO4)).

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkImage2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/checkProgess2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Checking for Service..." />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Initializing** (after `OnCreate` and `OnActivityResult`)

```
 private void initActivity() {
    imageRoot.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    imageService.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    progRoot.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    progService.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    textRoot.setText("checking for root..."); //TODO
    textService.setText("checking for service..."); //TODO
    layoutInfo.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);        
    CheckForRoot checkRootTask = new CheckForRoot();
    checkRootTask.execute(AppName.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra(APPNAME)));
}
```

Do you have any idea what the cause for the problem could be?

[Have a look at the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1epWcVcdPO4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working with changing the `FrameLayout`'s

```
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
    android:layout_height="48dip"
```

Still, I have no idea why this happened - in case you know why, please let me know!